# How do I write a route in ExpressJS to indicate a change in session state?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to Express, so please forgive me if this is obvious -- or if I'm not phrasing it correctly.

I'm writing a simple app which allows a user to upload and delete files via Node FS, as well as to add directories and navigate around the file structure.  Sort of a "mini Google drive". I'm maintaining state in a `session` variable using `express-session` and keeping the user's "current working directory" stored in the user's `session`.  This "current working directory" (`userpath`) is used as a reference for getting a list of that directory's files for use in my `app.get('files')` route, passing it to `fs.readdirSync`

```
fs.readdirSync(userpath)
```

My question is: how to "go up a level" in the file structure?  That is, if I add a link (in the Pug template that represents the 'files' page) to go up a level, what is the `href` I use to signal to the backend that I wish to both change the session state (changing the current working directory in my `session` variable) and do redisplay the files in the `files` route?

Do I use an entirely new route, e.g. `/files/changedirectory` whose route handler's purpose is to change the session variable and then `res.redirect` to the `files` route?  Would it better to design something with either route parameters or query parameters?  Or is there a better way entirely to handle this?

I'm a bit confused, I believe, as I'm trying to learn how to handle procedural programming using REST endpoints.  Thanks for any help.